# For loop unexpected increment value

Tags: javascript

So I understand why clicking on any button would pop up "Button [last value of i in loop] but why does i == 5 and not 4?

```
function myFn() {
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   var len = elems.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
      elems[i].onclick = function() {           
          alert ("Button " + i); 
      };
   }
   alert ("Button " + i); 

}
myFn();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka_tee_jean/fCtC8/

Comment: Because `i == 5` is the condition that stops the for loop from executing its body.

Comment: i feel stupid... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value of `i` variable is `5` at the end of the loop. So the `alert` statement inside `myFn()` will say "Button 5" on page load. The alert statements inside functions inside the for loop refer to **the same** variable via closure scope. Hence the clicks on the buttons also alert "Button 5".

Hope it helps! See below function which prints what you want. The caveat is introducing another closure scope by duplicating the value (pass-by-value mechanism in JavaScript) of i so that the onclick functions refer to **another variable** (`i`) which has a **copy of the value**.

```
function myFn() {
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   var len = elems.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
       (function(i) {
           elems[i].onclick = function() {           
              alert ("Button " + i); 
          };
       })(i);
   }
   alert ("Button " + i); 

}

myFn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the function like:

**js**

```
function myFn() {
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   var len = elems.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
      elems[i].onclick = function() {
          alert (this.innerHTML); 
      };
   }
   alert ("Button " + i); 

}

myFn();
```

As @Hunter McMillen mention `i==5` is the condition that stops the loop.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCtC8/5/)

Comment: This wan't the question but thanks for posting this for those who didn't understand that part